# XAMPP-VM Mac OS Mojave wordpress debugging using XDebug

Tags: php, debug, xampp, wp-debug, mac

Someone please point me to a knowldge article or information on
how to setup **Xdebug on XAMPP-VM Mac OS in particular**.

The dev configuration:

- XAMPP-VM
- Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6
- VScode with PHP debug plugin
- Wordpress installed on XAMPP-VM

---

**Steps tried:** Followed the instructions as per this [link](https://hackmd.io/@OoNs-lHwSqi4rzf0yP6uQA/SJgCQ3hoQ?type=view)

1. Copied **Xdebug.so** to the extension folder inside XAMPP-VM & configured
   **php.ini** for xdebug values as below

   > ```
   > [XDebug]
   > xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   > xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
   > xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
   > zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/xdebug/xdebug.so"
   > ```
2. Mapped the localhost port 9000 as below

[image]

3. Added debug configuration to my **VScode** with **php debug** plugin installed.
4. I have checked **phpinfo** which prints **with xdebug** (Just to
   make sure the plugin is enabled)

> **PS: I googled around and failed to get the solution**. What am i missing here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. As this site is not really about link distribution, but about problem solving, you might want to [edit] the question and explain how far you got, where you got stuck and how to reproduce your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser update the question in detail. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After days of struggle to enable debugging, I switched to [MAMP free version](https://www.mamp.info/en/) which was a cakewalk.

For Step by step guide please follow this [blog by Josh Buchea](https://joshbuchea.com/enable-xdebug-in-mamp-for-mac/). Has a detailed walkthrough.

---

*Hope this helps someone stuck on Mac with Xampp-VM like i did. Switch to MAMP free version. Happy coding Wordpress PHP*